# subtraction of 2 select statements

Tags: sql, plsql

I have a simple table:

Neighbourhood

```
 code neighbourhood country
```

Some countries have the same neighborhood name. All I want is the total minus the distinct. but I have a problem with the operator; Here is what I am doing.

```
 select count(*)- select distinct(neighbourhood) from Neighbourhood
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want:

```
select count(*) - count(distinct neighbourhood)
from Neighbourhood;
```

I might suggest a further breakdown:

```
select cnt, count(*), min(neighbourhood), max(neighbourhood)
from (select neighbourhood, count(*) as cnt
      from neighbourhood
      group by neighbourhood
     ) n
group by cnt
order by cnt;
```

This shows the frequency of duplication along with example value of `neighbourhood`.

Answer (score 0):

use `count(distinct neighbourhood)` and `distinct` is not a function

```
select count(*)- select count(distinct neighbourhood) from Neighbourhood
```